# How to create the multiple cells when i select row in UItableview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitableview

I have number of some names have in tableview when I click the particular Name the tableview want to reload and add some more cells from selected name.then again click the sub cell and load some more cell. How can I do this any one help me

Comment: It's a great pain-in-the-ass what you want to do. You wanna expand cell's info once tapped by creating some subcells in the same table? And sub-subcells? It is never imposible but illogic. Well, maybe not illogic, but you will get a bunch of weird code.

Comment: @TeodorCarstea Thanks for your reply. This is possible or not when i click the row loaded some cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a delegate which is called whenever you select a cell from the table

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


NSLog(@"*****you have selected a cell ********* ");

NSLog(@"selected cell row = %i and section = %i",indexPath.row,indexPath.section);

// Add more data to the array which is populating the table so that to add more cells

[your_Table reloadData]; // This will reload your table with new data which you added to your Array 

}
```

Comment: how to add the row at run time

Comment: @yuvaraj There must be an Array which you are using to populate the table just add some more data to that array before reloading the table this will work